# The best directory to install a font

Tags: fonts, installing

What difference exists between installing a font in `~/Library/texmf` and in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`?

Which of the two positions takes less resources and allows a faster compilation?

Is there a better position?

Comment: And what you mean by "takes less resources"? The main difference between this to: `~/Library/texmf` is local user fonts folder and next one is a global fonts folder. There is no difference where to put fonts in terms of access speed or whatever.

Comment: What sort of font are we taking here? A 'traditional' TeX one needs to go into a TeX tree while a modern OpenType one is probably best installed system wide for all applications.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3):

If you are installing a 'traditional' TeX font (with `.tfm` files, a `.map` etc.), then the best place is `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`. This is the best position not because it uses resources more efficiently but because it is much easier to maintain. If you use `~/Library/texmf`, then you will need to intervene manually when you update your TeX Live installation in order to maintain proper access to all your fonts.

But, as Joseph mentioned in the comments, if you are installing an opentype font, for example, you should install it as a system font just as you'd install any other font for OS X.